# Append Text to paragraph on button click in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am doing a web based calculator wherein I want to append each and every number pressed on to a paragraph, this is the paragraph to hold all the entered input `<p id="display" class="col-10 table-bordered" style="height:20px"></p>` then this is one of the buttons `<button class="col-2" id="seven">7</button>`
Then below is the jQuery code used to try and captured the data

```
@section scripts {
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#seven").click(function () {

            //document.getElementById('display').text('7') = $('#seven').text();
            $("#display").append('7');
        });
    });
</script>
```

The problem is when I click on button 7, the number appears once on the display and disappears, I think it is refreshing or something, I cant seem to get the number to stick once it has been clicked, please help.

Comment: Sounds like buttons are in a form. The default type for `<button>` is "submit" which will cause page to reload due to default form process. Try `type="button"`

Comment: @charlietfl that was the issue indeed, I just upvoted your comment, I added them inside the form because I will later need to submit whatever user has entered